# ASP.NET MVC - Optionally Redirect from a Base Class Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionmethod

Consider the following block of code that reappears in many of my controller actions. (I'm chiefly concerned with the first 6 lines of the method body).

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult OptOut()
{
    var user = this.SecurityPrincipal;
    if (user.IsReadOnlyUser)
    {
        this.TempData["ViewModel"] = new AuthorizationModel { User = user };
        return this.RedirectToAction("NotAuthorized", "Authorization");
    }

    var model = /* Elided for brevity */

    return this.View(model);
}
```

My controllers derive from a base class, `SecuredController` which, in turn, derives from `Controller`. `SecurityPrincipal` is a property of `SecuredController`, and contains extensive Active Directory data about the current user.

In an effort to eliminate duplicate code, I'd ideally like to move the functionality contained in the `if {...}` block into a base class method, but I can't think of any way to do so, since the return type of the method would have to be `ActionResult`, resulting in something ungainly like this:

```
if ((var result = this.RequireReadWrite()) != null)
{
    return result;
}
```

Can anyone suggest a way to do this, or am I simply out of luck here?

Comment: What about using [MVC Action Filters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs)? Have you considered that in your design? You'd have more control with the `filterContext` on what the `ActionResult` should be.

Comment: A Filter sounds appropriate.

Comment: In general, if you're doing security in your methods, you're doing it wrong.  Security is a cross cutting concern, and should be handled way before you even get to executing the method.  As mentioned, filters are a better way to handle this, and something that MVC has an entire framework for.  You're trying to roll your own security, and that's almost always an anti-pattern.  Essentially, you have an expensive and well tested security system on your house, and you're leaving the door unlocked and asking a bored teenager to make sure the house is safe.

Comment: @QuantumHive That did the trick. Can't believe I missed that. :( I need an answer so I can upvote and accept. Then I will summarily present myself for a right fonging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, especially noting that security is a [cross cutting concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) we've suggested using [MVC Action Filters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) to be applied in your use case and design.
Microsoft's documentation is pretty informative and there are more examples that can be found on the web on how to use *MVC Filters*. I'll try to provide an example, but this will be based on a lot of assumptions on your software architecture, since I simply don't have the knowledge of that.

You could create the following class:

```
public class SecuredFilterAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    ...
}
```

If using a [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) framework, you could inject the `SecurityPrincipal` service. But again I don't know the architecture of your application, so it's up to you how you create that dependency.
When overriding the `AuthorizeCore`, you could implement it like so:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    return !this.SecurityPrinciple.IsReadOnlyUser;
}
```

And when not authorized override the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method to redirect:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    var redirectRoute = ...; //your route to redirect to an unauthorized page
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectRoute);
    //do some other things, for example, setting some tempdata information
}
```

Again it's up to you on how you would use this *Filter*. You could register it globally, or apply it on a per controller or action basis. To register it globally, in your startup:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new SecuredFilterAttribute());
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend [SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html) as your DI Container.

Comment: Thanks very much. This was almost exactly what I did, and it works perfectly. Since I need this on only a few action methods, I decided to decorate those methods with the attributes rather than registering a global handler. Again, thanks!